Usage of images from internet
A question that often comes to my mind is whether/under what conditions can one use images found in the internet on stack exchange. Particularly the images from Wikipedia.
Whenever I use an image, I always supply a link to the page where I borrowed it from - however, I wonder whether this is sufficient?
Related: Stack exchange guidelines on image sharing

Depends on the licence of the original image!

@ACuriousMind could you provide a more specific guidelines: what should license say (or do not say) to add the image on Physics SE? Perhaps, the question is more appropriate for the general SE meta, rather than just for physics... but in physics images are rather important.

I think a mini-lesson in intellectual property and licensing is beyond the scope of a comment. But the "share" button on Wikipedia images always includes some boilerplate HTML which identifies the author of the image, the image's license, and a link back to the source.

@rob the question is not about intellectual property, but about the SE policies/guidelines on the subject.

Well, SE policy and guidelines are "don't break the law", which includes breaching copyright.

On the level of copyright licensing agreements, only the license under which the original image is licensed can tell you how to properly attribute an image (or any other content). For instance, new content posted to any SE site is licensed under CC-BY-SA 4.0 and the Creative Commons Wiki has a dedicated page for recommended practices for attribution.
On the level of academic honesty/preventing the appearance of plagiarism, we have only minimal required features of an attribution - if possible, link the source (and in any case provide some unambiguous name that identifies the source) and name the original author.
See also the help center on "How to reference material written by others" for more details and an example.
